# Binding with the inner DataGrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having problem to bind with an inner DataGrid. The binding works with the DataGrid "Account" but not with "Record". I am using DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate for the second Datagrid

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Account">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AccountNumber}" Header="Account Number" FontSize="16"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" FontSize="16"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RecordList,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Record" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RecordNumber}" Header="Record Number" FontSize="16"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" FontSize="16"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>

</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="Account Number:"> <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Account, Path=SelectedItem.AccountNumber}" x:Name="ANr"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Record Number:"> <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Record, Path=SelectedItem.RecordNumber}" x:Name="RecordText"/>

</Grid>
```

The error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Record'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.RecordNumber; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='RecordText'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The first TextBox binds without a problem. The second one fails to bind.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your inner `DataGrid` name `Record` is valid only in context of your `DataTemplate`. This data template will be repeated for each row so cannot really bind to control by name. What you need to do instead you have to bind through `SelectedItem` of outer `DataGrid` but for that you will need something in `Account` object to say which row has been selected in inner grid. So first you need to create `SelectedRecord` in `Account` class, bind it you inner grid to `SelectedItem` and then you can do that:

```
<TextBlock Text="Record Number:"> 
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Account, 
   Path=SelectedItem.SelectedReocrd.RecordNumber}" 
   x:Name="RecordText"/>
```

Comment: In Account class i have RecordList(ObservableCollection), string Name, int AccountNumber. How can i create SelectedRecord?

Comment: for example in your `Account` class create `SelectedRecord` property of the same type as your `RecordList` item and bind it to `SelectedItem` of inner `DataGrid` in the same way you bind `RecordList`

Comment: But how can i bind the SelectedRecord with the selected item. If i just create SelectedRecord in Account and write Binding ElementName=Account, 
   Path=SelectedItem.SelectedReocrd.RecordNumber i dont get anything because SelectedRecord is NULL

Comment: exactly in the same way as you did with `RecordList`: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RecordList,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRecord, Mode=TwoWay}">`

Comment: It almost works. The only problem is that it binds only to the first row, no matter where i click.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you set breakpoint in the setter of the `SelectedRecord` property and checked it's called only once? Or maybe your `Account` class does not raise `PropertyChanged` event when `SelectedRecord` changes, or event does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx))? Until you will implement that interface and raise that event each time `SelectedRecord` changes anything you bind to it will not know that property has changed.

Comment: I put UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and it works. Thank you